# Basic properties of the Radon transform

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms

[image]

This is a page from Evan's PDEs where the Radon transform is defined.

I have three brief questions:
(1)   It says the integrals
$\int_{\Pi(s,\omega)}\nabla u\cdot b_{i}\,dS$ vanish because the vectors $b_{i}$ are parallel to the plane  $\Pi(s,\omega)$ and $u$ has compact support.

I am a little confused because I understand that the vectors $b_{i}$ are parallel to the plane $\Pi(s,\omega)$; they generate the plane. It is also evident that $\nabla u\cdot b_{i}$ is the length of the projection of the vector $\nabla u$ in the direction $b_{i}$, and $|\nabla u|$ compact support (because $u$ is assumed to have compact support). Now,  the scalar function $\nabla u\cdot b_{i}$ can live entirely or partly in the support of $\nabla u$. So why must the integral vanish.

(2) why does not $\int_{\Pi(s,\omega)}\nabla u\cdot A\, dS$ vanish for any vector $A$ ? (after all the gradient $\nabla u$ is compactly supported)

(3) Finally, it is stated that $\tilde{u}_{s}=\int_{\Pi(s,\omega)}\nabla u\cdot \omega\, dS$. How come ? I am guessing by a change of variables (precisely a scaling $y\rightarrow y/s$) but not sure how to formulate it.

Apologies for the long question, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), work out the case when $b_i=e_1$, so you're integrating $\partial u/\partial x_1$. Integrate over a giant rectangle containing the support of $u$ in $\Pi(s,\omega)$. By Fubini's Theorem, integrate first with respect to $x_1$, and you end up with $0$.

For (2), imagine $A=e_n$ create a compactly supported function $u$ with $\int_{x_n=c} \partial u/\partial x_n\,dS > 0$.

For (3), parametrize $\Pi(s,\omega)$ by taking any parametrization of $\Pi(0,\omega)$ and adding $s\omega$. Now write down the integral over $\Pi(0,\omega)$ and differentiate with respect to $s$ under the integral sign.

Comment: Thank you prof. Shifrin for your amazing continuous support to MS. About (2), you mean integrate over the line $\{x_{n}=c\}\cap \Pi(s,\omega)$ rather than the plane $\{x_{n}=c\}$, assuming $e_{n}$ is orthogonal to the plane$\Pi(s,\omega)$.  No?

Comment: For (3), indeed, we could write $\Pi(s,\omega)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: (y-s\omega)\cdot \omega=0\}$.

Comment: I understand well your generously detailed explanation for (1). It just opens a different question to me: Suppose ${e_{i}}$ is the usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $S$ be a proper subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, say of dimension $n-1$ and with basis $\{b_i\}$. Then we can use the linear change of basis map to express  $b_i$ as a linear combination of all the $n$ vectors $e_i$. Can we drop one of the vectors $e_{i}$ in all these representations ?

Comment: For (2), no, I meant that you should consider the case $A=\omega$. For (1) it's probably best, in general, to parametrize $\Pi(s,\omega)$ by using the orthonormal basis $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$ and then the argument I suggested for the special case goes through immediately.